# Updated Django version giving conflicting migrations in installed "contenttypes" app

Tags: django-migrations

I just upgraded from Django 2.2.6 to 4.0.3.

When I try to run my app locally, I see:

```
You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
```

When I try to run the migrations, I get:

```
CommandError: Conflicting migrations detected; multiple leaf nodes in the migration graph: (0001_initial 2, 0002_remove_content_type_name, 0002_remove_content_type_name 2 in contenttypes; 0001_initial 2, 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length 2, 0003_alter_user_email_max_length 2, 0004_alter_user_username_opts 2, 0005_alter_user_last_login_null 2, 0006_require_contenttypes_0002 2, 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages 2, 0008_alter_user_username_max_length 2, 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length 2, 0010_alter_group_name_max_length 2, 0011_update_proxy_permissions 2, 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length, 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length 2 in auth; 0001_initial, 0001_initial 2 in sessions; 0001_initial 2, 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add 2, 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices, 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices 2 in admin).
To fix them run 'python manage.py makemigrations --merge'
```

If I try to run the merge command, I get:

```
ValueError: Could not find common ancestor of ['0001_initial', '0001_initial 2']
```

It seems to be coming from the built in contenttypes app:

```
python ./manage.py  showmigrations contenttypes
contenttypes
 [ ] 0001_initial 2
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
 [ ] 0002_remove_content_type_name 2
```

How can I edit the migrations of a built in app?  I'd like to remove the duplicate migrations so that they don't break my prod server when I deploy my app, but I can't find them anywhere.   Please help me :)

Comment: It seems this problem is isolated to my virtual environment.  Other environments don't show the warning about unapplied migrations.

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete your virtualenv, install new one and install all packages.
My problem has been fixed with this.